# Get the value of a cell in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, row

I have these columns:

```
columns: [
{data: 'values.0.2'},
{data: 'values.0.3'},
{data: 'values.0.4'},
]
```

I need to get its value separated by commas within a span like this:

```
render: function(data, type, row, meta){
var sequence = "<span class='row.bar'>"1,2,3</span>";
return sequence
```

In other words, you need this:

```
<span class='row.bar'>"VALUE ROW 1,VALUE ROW 2,VALUE ROW 3</span>";
```

Example:

If this:

```
columns: [
{data: 'values.0.2'},
{data: 'values.0.3'},
{data: 'values.0.4'},
]
```

Show this:

```
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
```

I need:

```
<span class='row.bar'>1,2,3</span>
```

Someone has knowledge on how to get this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it.
Add `data: null`
And now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cell()` method to select the cells you need, then use `data()` to get the values

docs: https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell() 
, https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()

I get this working in my local project like this:

`table.row(0).data()[0]`
or this
`table.row(0).cells().data()[0]`

I don't know why cell() isnt working propperly, according the docs we're using it well, btw, I think you can solve your problem this way :)

Comment: table.cell(3).data() and I get undefined.

Comment: did you try `table.cell(2).data()` ? the index start in 0

Comment: Yes. Example, this: var sequence = "<span class='bar'>"+table.cell(2).data()+"5,3,9,6,5,9,7,3,5,2</span>" Show this: <span>    undefined5,3,9,6,5,9,7,3,5,2</span>

Comment: I see, let me think a bit, I guess your var `table` doesn't return undefined :D

Comment: Thank you. The table shows the values correctly, what I need to refer to them in the span.

Comment: Check my edit, I think there's some problem with the documentation or something

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work either. It must be simple but I can not do it. Basically I need to recover the value of the cell.

Comment: I know what you are trying to achieve, but it's strange that it didn't give you the value...

It would be nice to see how do you initialize your datatable, or how do you declare the 'table' variable